How to configure a lightning-file-upload file drop zone size?
I am trying to change siz e of lightning-file-upload component file drop-zone but didn't get the requested result:
My HTML
        <lightning-card title="Upload CSV File and Update Record">
        <div class="file-upload-container">
            <lightning-file-upload
                label="Upload CSV File"
                accept=".csv"
                record-id={recordId}
                onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
                class="custom-drop-zone"
            ></lightning-file-upload>
            </div>
            <lightning-button label="Update Loan" onclick={createRecords}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-card>
</template>

My CSS
.file-upload-container {
    max-width: 600px; /* Set the maximum width as needed */
    width: 100%; /* Responsive width */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the component */
}

/* Optional: Customize the appearance */
lightning-file-upload {
    width: 100%; /* Ensure the component fills the container */
}

.custom-drop-zone {
    width: 100%; /* Ensure the drop zone spans the container */
    border: 2px dashed #0070d2; /* Customize the border of the drop zone */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
    padding: 20px; /* Add padding */
    background-color: #f4f6f9; /* Light background color */
}

and a result of this:


While this may not fully address your query, it could bring you closer to your desired outcome. I tested the code you provided and adjusted the slds-file-selector__body inner class to control the width of the 'Upload Files' button. You might consider customizing this CSS class further to suit your specific requirements.
.file-upload-container {
    max-width: 600px; /* Set the maximum width as needed */
    width: 100%; /* Responsive width */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the component */
}

/* Optional: Customize the appearance */
lightning-file-upload {
    width: 100%; /* Ensure the component fills the container */
}

.custom-drop-zone {
    width: 100%; /* Ensure the drop zone spans the container */
    border: 2px dashed #0070d2; /* Customize the border of the drop zone */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
    padding: 20px; /* Add padding */
    background-color: #f4f6f9; /* Light background color */
}

/* The Inner class controlling the width */
.slds-file-selector_files .slds-file-selector__body, .slds-file-selector--files .slds-file-selector__body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 20%;
}

The JS file remains same
The attached image demonstrates the adjustment to the width of the 'Upload Files' button. Feel free to modify this property further to better meet your needs.

